# Calibre can optionally use a server to send mail

Tags: kindle, calibre, amazon, ebook-management, send-to-kindle

I tried `calibre` share/send to, but it failed with:

```
Sending failed...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/gui2/email.py", line 44, in run
    self.func(*self.args)
```

I was just curious, really, how `calibre` sends to my Kindle account because I don't recall authorizing it, nor do I see sent messages from it.  (Not that I configured it with my `e-mail` settings.)

Does Amazon just "trust" the `calibre` software?  if so, good.  Curious.

Yes, I suppose I could go look in the above python script...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calibre uses the address that was entered in the **Sharing books by email** dialog box. Apparently, the developer didn't anticipate that someone would try to use send without configuring email settings.

You might want to contact him and [let him know about this issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/calibre). (He usually fixes problems the very same day.)

Comment: yes, I entered an e-mail address (didn't realize that).  My point is that I never provided a password -- so the e-mail isn't really "from" me, it's from `Calibre`.  Which is kinda curious.  I'm thankful that it works, and, no I don't want a ton of attachments in my sent mail box.  So `Calibre` must be sending through their own server...no?  There's an **option** to provide credentials.